# Computer Shuts Down while Connecting Internet

Tags: networking, internet

I know that this is not exactly a programming question, but it has amused me since last 4-5 days, and I'm unable to find the cause.

I just got a wireless modem+router, after doing the installation, the wireless connection on my laptop is working fine, but the LAN cable is connecting to an old PC running windows XP.

Whenever I open a browser on my PC, it shuts down automatically after a few minutes.

If I detach the LAN cable, I don't face this problem. Initially in the windows event viewer I found that the router acting as DHCP server wasn't assigning the IP address to PC, so I assigned a static IP to it, but still the problem exists.

Has anybody faced similar problem?

Comment: This belongs on [su]

Comment: 1. This question belongs to Super User.

2. Maybe your computer gets over-heated because the browser's work and shuts down? Try to open the computer, and clean up all the dust (yes, inside the fans and heat sinks).